# Calculations of chiral condensate (from David Tong's notes)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, chirality

I got confused on the calculation of chiral condensate in [David Tong's Gauge theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html). The equation 3.52 reads
\begin{equation}
\langle\bar{\psi}_{-}\psi_{+}\rangle=\big(\prod_{n}\lambda_n\big)\frac{1}{2}\big(\sum_{l}\frac{1}{\lambda_l}\bar{\phi}_l(1+\gamma^5)\phi_l\big),\tag{3.52}
\end{equation}
where $\phi_l$'s are eigenspinors of Dirac operator $i\gamma\cdot D$, $\lambda_l$ is the corresponding eigenvalue. Since $\gamma^5$ and Dirac operator are anticommuting, then $\gamma^5\phi_l$ is another eigenspinor of eigenvalue $-\lambda_l$.

Below eq 3.52, it says "*This means that the sum over $\lambda_l^{-1}$ will contain equal and opposite contribution*..". But I cannot recover this point. I did the calculation as follows:

For fixed $\phi_l$ of eigenvalue $\lambda_l$, there is a $\phi'_l=\gamma^5\phi_l$ of eigenvalue $-\lambda_l$, so
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{-\lambda_l}\bar{\phi'_l}(1+\gamma^5)\phi'_l=\frac{1}{-\lambda_l}\phi^{\dagger}_l\gamma^5\gamma^0(1+\gamma^5)\gamma^5\phi_l=\frac{1}{\lambda_l}\phi^{\dagger}_l\gamma^0\gamma^5(1+\gamma^5)\gamma^5\phi_l=\frac{1}{\lambda_l}\bar{\phi_l}(1+\gamma^5)\phi_l,
\end{equation}
where we used $\{\gamma^5,\gamma^0\}=0$. So the positive and the negative cannot cancel out! What's wrong with my calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crucial piece of context is that this calculation is done in the Euclidean (after a Wick rotation). In the Euclidean, $\bar{\psi}$ is just considered an independent field from $\psi$, and $\bar{\psi} = \psi^\dagger \gamma^0$ does not hold (eg see after Eq 3.21). So you don't pick up the minus sign from $\{\gamma_0,\gamma_5\}=0$.

Comment: Thanks very much. But I'm not familiar with conventions in Euclidean spactime. Is the $\bar{\psi}$ in Euclidean spactime understood as $\psi^{\dagger}$?

Comment: @Sven2009 Not quite, see Eq 16 here for a prescription for the canonical formalism: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9608174 (van Nieuwenhuizen and Waldron, 1996). Also see Eqs 1 and 2 for how things work in the path integral formalism.